# angular file upload converting data/payload into string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I have been using ng-file-upload to upload files to server. Recently I saw that it is converting payload/data that I am adding to it apart from file from any data type to string only. For example if I am sending integer or boolean field, it is converting it into string.
I am using django at backend, so when I print type of request data it is showing unicode and in model I have defined NullBooleanField. Because of this everytime it takes it True and save it in database as True. Below is the little snippet of what I am doing.

```
var _data = {'name': 'xxx',' good':false};

$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
 url: URL,
 method: 'PUT',
 file: data_file,
 data: _data,}).progress(function(evt){
});
```

each time when I print the type of this at backend

```
type(print (request.DATA['good'])))
```

it return

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

Am i missing something here or something is actually wrong?

Comment: send JSON toy preserve types, POST is all strings

Comment: But this `_data`  is a JSON. Its seems like this $upload is converting json data into string. (My guess is there internal implementation is like they convert each payload into string and then send it to server.)